# How to define CRITERIA in ACCESS QUERY to be taken from a field in another table?

Tags: ms-access, criteria

I have created a simple query with filtering criteria for date, which I typed manually in design form of the query.

```
    SELECT tbl_CountryDefs.Country_Name, tbl_CRatings.CReportDate, tbl_CRatings.CRating
    FROM tbl_CRatings INNER JOIN tbl_CountryDefs ON tbl_CRatings.CCountry = tbl_CountryDefs.CMAPPING
    WHERE (((tbl_CRatings.CReportDate)="2013-JAN"))
    ORDER BY tbl_CountryDefs.Country_Name;
```

If I create a new table with a criteria definition as field, how can I without any macros or VBA to define criteria in that query to look up for the value of the field in the new table?

Comment: You want the whole line `WHERE (((tbl_CRatings.CReportDate)="2013-JAN"))`, which is not possible without VBA, or just 2013-JAN, which could probably be more easily be done some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood you can achieve what you're looking for with a simple `DLookup`. If you create a new table (say called QueryCriteria, with one Text field called ReportDate), then the following should work:

```
SELECT tbl_CountryDefs.Country_Name, tbl_CRatings.CReportDate, tbl_CRatings.CRating
FROM tbl_CRatings INNER JOIN tbl_CountryDefs ON tbl_CRatings.CCountry = tbl_CountryDefs.CMAPPING
WHERE tbl_CRatings.CReportDate = DLookup("ReportDate","QueryCriteria")
ORDER BY tbl_CountryDefs.Country_Name;
```

In this example, if the `ReportDate` in the `QueryCriteria` table had a value of `2013-JAN`, it would achieve the same as your original hard-coded query.

Comment: Why not a JOIN it would be quicker? Also, I have some doubts about the value of what appears to be a one-field, one row table.

Comment: A JOIN would work too (and is likely quicker) but this seemed like a quick solution when there's only one criteria and kept the structure of the query largely intact (so it's easy to understand). A one field, one row 'criteria' table is valuable when you are using the same parameter value in many queries, as you only have one place to update it.

Comment: thanks, this worked `WHERE tbl_CRatings.CReportDate =DLookup("ReportDate","QueryCriteria")` (without "'") –

Comment: Glad you got sorted. Edited answer to reflect :)